# Unity: How do you create a fully working InputField in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a **"UnityEngine.UI.InputField"** via script in C#. Since the Unity API docs lack extremely in terms of code examples and therefore are as helpful as a rock chained to your feet I'm trying to re-create it from an **InputField** added in the editor.

I have

- created the InputField,
- added an **Image** component for background,
- a **Text** component for the actual input text and
- a **Text** for the placeholder.
- I've also added an **EventSystem** to my scene.

Everything looks visually alright but the input isn't working. Clicking on the field doesn't seem to do anything.

What else needs to be done to get this working properly so that text input works?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention: The manually placed InputField gets a InputField Input Caret child object when run. But my C# InputField does not get this automatically. How can this be added?

```
GameObject container = new GameObject();
container.name = "InputField";
container.transform.parent = _console.transform;
container.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();

_image = container.AddComponent<Image>();
_image.color = Utils.HexToColor32("0000000A");

GameObject textContainer = new GameObject();
textContainer.name = "Text";
textContainer.transform.parent = container.transform;
_text = textContainer.AddComponent<Text>();
_text.supportRichText = false;
_text.color = _console.colorText;
_text.font = _console.fontFace;
_text.fontSize = _console.fontSize;
_text.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;

GameObject placeholderContainer = new GameObject();
placeholderContainer.name = "Placeholder";
placeholderContainer.transform.parent = container.transform;
_placeholder = placeholderContainer.AddComponent<Text>();
_placeholder.color = new Color(_console.colorText.r, _console.colorText.g, _console.colorText.b, _console.colorText.a / 2);
_placeholder.font = _console.fontFace;
_placeholder.fontSize = _console.fontSize;
_placeholder.fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
_placeholder.supportRichText = false;
_placeholder.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;
_placeholder.text = "Enter command ...";

_inputField = container.AddComponent<InputField>();
_inputField.targetGraphic = _image;
_inputField.textComponent = _text;
_inputField.placeholder = _placeholder;
```

Comment: could you please provide a copy of your code so that we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: I've added the relevant code block.

Comment: @Rohit Why removed my sourcecode?

Comment: I did not remove it, I just checked in the old copy, it was not there.  Maybe it was a timing issue and my edited copy before you added the source code got saved as you were saving the source code.  Please add it again.

Comment: Now that it looks like a decent question, I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The canvas this runs on needs a GraphicsRaycaster component.